# Aggregate multiple lookups return no data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have documents like this in DB. And I need to grab the data of each item based on the `itemType` from their own collection.

```
      { listId: 2, itemType: 'book', itemId: 5364 },
      { listId: 2, itemType: 'car', itemId: 354 },
      { listId: 2, itemType: 'laptop', itemId: 228 }
```

Based on MongoDB docs and some search, I figured out that I need to use `let` and `$expr` in lookup, to make some condition.

```
ListItemsModel.aggregate([
    { $match: { listId: 2 } },
    { $lookup:
       {
         from: 'books',
         localField: 'itemId',
         foreignField: '_id',
         let: { "itemType": "$itemType" },
         pipeline: [
            { $project: { _id: 1, title: 1 }},
            { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$itemType", "book"] } }}
         ],
         as: 'data'
       }
     },
     { $lookup:
        {
          from: 'cars',
          localField: 'itemId',
          foreignField: '_id',
          let: { "itemType": "$itemType" },
          pipeline: [
             { $project: { _id: 1, title: 1 }},
             { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$itemType", "car"] } }}
          ],
          as: 'data'
        }
      },
      { $lookup:
       {
         from: 'laptops',
         localField: 'itemId',
         foreignField: '_id',
         let: { "itemType": "$itemType" },
         pipeline: [
            { $project: { _id: 1, title: 1 }},
            { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$itemType", "laptop"] } }}
         ],
         as: 'data'
       }
     }
    ]);
```

The problem is, in the result all data fields are empty as `data: []`.
The syntax seems correct to me. What's wrong?

Comment: Please try to show the sample data for your `cars`, `books`, `laptops` collections and also your expected output. While based on what I read from your aggregate query, you are keeping overriding the `data` array in each stage, hence you may lose data if the further stage returns empty array or different result.

Comment: Without diving into any details, I notice that each `"$lookup"` has `as: 'data'`.  That means that any subsequent `"$lookup"` will overwrite the previous `"$lookup"` `"data"`.

Comment: @YongShun documents in `cars` `books` `laptops` all have `_id` and `title` field. Which I filtered by projection.

Comment: @rickhg12hs do you mean I should omit that part?

Comment: You need to, for example, assign different values to `"as"` ... something like `"booksData"`, `"carsData"`, `"laptopsData"`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I changed `as` name in each `lookup` to different names and it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: @rickhg12hs can you post the answer so I can mark it as correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any subsequent reassignment of field values will eliminate any previous value.

So, for your aggregation pipeline, you need to assign different values to each `"$lookup"` `"as"` field.

For example:

```js
     // ...
     { $lookup:
       {
         from: 'books',
         // ...
         as: 'booksData'
       }
     },
     { $lookup:
       {
         from: 'cars',
         // ...
         as: 'carsData'
       }
     },
     { $lookup:
       {
         from: 'laptops',
         // ...
         as: 'laptopsData'
       }
     },
     // ...
```